# Div doesn't send object below another object

Tags: javascript, html, css-float

Please check this codepen: 
https://codepen.io/Bhoopalan/pen/KybKRy

```
<div row id="container">
<div class="box">Box1</div>
<div class="box">Box2</div>
<div class="box">Box3</div>
</div>
<div>
<button>Click Me</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="effects.js"></script>
```

I have created 3 boxes and a "click me" button. All these four objects are on separate divs. 
I wanted the 3 boxes to be on same line and the click me button to be below the boxes. So in css I wrote as follows

```
    .box {
    background: purple;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    max-width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Using float for .box, I expected the boxes only to float left. To my surprise, the button which was in separate div is also floating left to the boxes. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need to add a [mcve] to the _question_ rather than an link to off-site code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `float: left;` you should use the css [display property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

```
display: inline-block;
```

also, `row` is not a valid html attribute. :)

```css
.box {
  background: purple;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">Box1</div>
  <div class="box">Box2</div>
  <div class="box">Box3</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much. But I'm still confused about why float was applying to the button when I entered it inside the box class